# How can I get other root data in component under the v-for statement?

Tags: vue.js

I also want to access add string in the template but it seems like not work.
please help me solve my problem here...

```
Vue.component('comp',{
    template:`
        <div id="test">
            <div v-for="(item,index) in this.$root.items">
                <p>{{this.$root.string}}</p>
                <p>{{item}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    `
})

var vm = new Vue({
    el:'#test',
    data:function(){
        return {
            'string':'xxx',
            'items':['a','b','c']
        }
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/89kgnrvf/5/

Comment: if one of the answers solved your problem, please kindly upvote and approve for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

change `this.$root.items` to `$root.items`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to prefix with `this.` when you're inside the template of your component.

So, you just have to replace `this.$root.items` by `$root.items` and `this.$root.string` by `$root.string`.

However, you need to prefix with `this.` if you're referencing the value inside your `Vue` object.

**Example :**

```
computed: {     
    exampleComputed: function () {
        return this.string;
     }
}
```

And the corrected JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/89kgnrvf/19/